# Texts with hashtag (#) when passed as req.query dissapears in backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to pass a string with hashtag in the `req.query` to be parsed as JSON.

```
http://localhost:3000/link/?items=[{"quantity":1,"_id":"00001","box":"item01","desc":"#description1"}]
```

But when it reaches the backend (Node + Express) `req.query` becomes

```
{
  items: '[{"quantity":1,"_id":"00001","box":"item01","desc":"'
}
```

as you can see the description with hashtag just disappeared thus triggers `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input* when being parsed as JSON`.

Comment: You need to URL encode your `items` parameter. In particular, the `#` character.

Comment: i.e. `http://localhost:3000/link/?items=%5B%7B%22quantity%22%3A1%2C%22_id%22%3A%2200001%22%2C%22box%22%3A%22item01%22%2C%22desc%22%3A%22%23description1%22%7D%5D`

Comment: is there a way I can do this dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
let url = 'http://localhost:3000/link/?items=' 
  + encodeURIComponent('[{"quantity":1,"_id":"00001","box":"item01","desc":"#description1"}]');
```

Comment: It worked when I passed the example you provided butI am using a method to pass value to the url

```window.location.href = "/return/?items="+ encodeURIComponent(this.selectedItems);```

In the backend it sends [Object Object]

Comment: it did not parsing the req.query values gives me SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @Kevz `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))`